# How do I know if an item has been changed in my list?

Tags: c#, orm, tracking

I'm currently trying to build my own little OR-Mapper.
Like EF, I have a context and a set class.
As example:

```
public class As400Context : IDisposable
{
    public As400Set<MyClass> MyList{ get; set; }
}
```

At the moment, changes being tracked in MyClass.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private HashSet<string> ChangedProperties = new HashSet<string>();
    private Dictionary<string, object> OriginalValues = new 
    Dictionary<string, object>();
    private readonly ChangeState State = new ChangeState();

    public List<string> GetChangedProperties()
    {
        return ChangedProperties.ToList();
    }

    private void Setter(string field, object value)
    {
        OriginalValues.TryGetValue(field, out object originalValue);
        if (originalValue == null)
        {
            OriginalValues.Add(field, GetType().GetField('_' + field, 
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(this));
        }

        if (value.ToString() != originalValue.ToString())
        {
            ChangedProperties.Add(field);
        }
        else
        {
            ChangedProperties.Remove(field);
            OriginalValues.Remove(field);
        }
    }

    private string _Item;
    public string Item
    {
        get { return _Item; }
        set
        {
            Setter(nameof(Item), value);
            _Item = value;
        }
    }
}
```

---

T is MyClass

```
public class As400Set<T> : List<T>
{
    public new void Add(T obj)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            var state = obj.GetType().GetField("State", 
                        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            var stateValue = (ChangeState)state.GetValue(obj);
            if (stateValue != ChangeState.Modified)
                state.SetValue(obj, ChangeState.Added);

            base.Add(obj);
        }
    }

    public new void Remove(T obj)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            obj.GetType().GetField("State", BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                  BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(obj, ChangeState.Removed);
        }
    }
}
```

I do not think that's the best way.
I would like to have a change tracker on context level. No problem for Add and remove, but how do I do that for modified list items?

For example:

```
    var context = new As400Context();
    var myList = context.MyList.FirstOrDefault();
    myList.Item= "Test";
```

Sorry for bad english, I hope you understand what I'm trying to achieve :)

EDIT: I also need to know which property changed.

Comment: I would not use reflection for that. I would use an interface for that. (that defines a State property). If a child objects implements that interface, you can typecast it and change the state. Reflection is way too slow and cumbersome for this purpose.

Comment: Also using reflection to determine the old value is not recommend. Just pass the old value aswell to the `Setter(string field, object value, object oldValue)` => `Setter(nameof(Item), value, _item);`

Comment: Thanks for the approaches!